# Python code to publish hyper files fails if size is >64mb

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to write code with sample listed in the below GitHub repo.

https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/7ff43088c5db678dec9b9e1cb2a8be1ad952100d/Community-Supported/publish-hyper/publish-hyper-file.py

This works only if the hyper file size is less than 64mb. Can someone please guide how do I make it work with large hyper files.

Comment: You get to first look up what the transfer size limits are for the API(s) you're using, because step one is to find out whether what you want to do is even possible.

Comment: Are you trying to create the .hyper then publish it or just publish an existing .hyper?

Answer (score 1):

The size of your `.hyper` publish is not 64mb, but if you want to publish a file greater than 64mb, you have to do so with an `Append to File Upload` as outlined [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_publishing.htm#append_to_file_upload).

If you want to use Python and the `tableauserverclient`, this size check process is done for you. The `datasources.publish` method auto checks for the `.hyper` size and sends in multiple parts or one single send depending on that size.